# Объединить json

Tags: php, json

Доброго вечера. Подскажите пожалуйста по json.

Получаю:

```
$data['movie'] = $this->Play_lib->getmovie($id);
$data['music'] = $this->Play_lib->getmusic($id);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Отдает:

```
{
  "movie": [
    {
      "id": "12",
      "title": "Test Movie",
      "image": "s00f04f3.jpg",
      "type": "movie"
    },
  ],
  "music": [
    {
      "id": "34",
      "title": "Test Music",
      "image": "57a9773a.jpg",
      "type": "music"
    }
  ]
}
```

Каким образом сделать чтобы отдавало так:

```
[
   {
     "id": "12",
     "title": "Test Movie",
     "image": "s00f04f3.jpg",
     "type": "movie"
   },
   {
     "id": "34",
     "title": "Test Music",
     "image": "57a9773a.jpg",
     "type": "music"
   }
]
```

Спасибо.

Comment: `$data['movie'] ` замените на `$data[] = ... `, с `music` аналогично

Comment: Спасибо. Удаляет "movie" и "music", но оставляет лишние []. Можно их как-то убрать?

Comment: а, это я не заметил. тут проблема  в том, что `getMovie` и `getMusic` возвращают массив из 1 элемента, а не просто объект. Если подразумевается что метод должен возварщать только один элемент, и вы можете изменить эти методы, то измените. Если не можете изменить, то необходимо извлечь первый(нулевой) элемент массива, уже после вызова методов. Банально это можно написать в виде `$this->Play_lib->getmovie($id)[0]` но это плохой способ, т.к.  случае, когда вернется пустой массив это приведет к ошибке.

Comment: Т.е. вам сначала нужно извлечь данные в переменную (`$x = $this->Play_lib->getmovie($id)`), а потом проверив, что элементов больше чем 1 (`if(count($x))`получить первый (`$x[0]`), Правда не ясно, что надо делать с оставшимися элементами массива, если они есть.

Comment: в общем оформил в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Итак, ключи `movie` И `music` в результирующем `json` получаете поскольку сами их туда и записываете. Чтобы избавиться от этих строковых ключей, просто добавьте элементы в массив:

```
$data[] = $this->Play_lib->getmovie($id);
$data[] = $this->Play_lib->getmusic($id);
```

Следующий вопрос - откуда берется вложенные скобки `"movie": [ { } ]`. Скобки эти обозначают, что результатом работы методов `getmovie/getmusic` являются массивы, которые в данном случае состоят из 1 элемента.
С виду, вызов `getmovie($id)` похож на извлечение одного элемента по указанному ID. Здесь вам виднее, и если метод должен возвращать единственный элемент, то измените его, чтобы так и было, и возвращался объект, а не массив из одного объекта.
С другой стороны, возможно недопонимание, когда `id` это идентификатор, к примеру, жанра, а `getmusic` возвращает список соответствующих композиций.

В любом случае, если вы не можете изменить вышеуказанные методы, а из результата работы методов вам необходим только один (или единственный) элемент, то ваш код должен принимать следующий вид:

```
$data[] = array_shift($this->Play_lib->getmovie($id));
$data[] = array_shift($this->Play_lib->getmovie($id));

echo json_encode($data);
```

Используемый метод [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-shift.php) возвращает первый элемент входного массива, или `null`.

Comment: Большое спасибо за такой развернутый ответ. Методом "тыка" решил проблему добавив **array_merge()**.

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы путем добавления *array_merge()*:

```
$movie = $this->Play_lib->getmovie($id);
$music = $this->Play_lib->getmusic($id);
echo json_encode(array_merge($movie, $music));
```